# Codeigniter - Adding values to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get a user to enter their details and then store those in a database using codeigniter. When I try and add an entry I get taken to the page where it says success but it does not add anything to the database.

Here are the model and the controller files -

1. signup.php - This is the controller

   ```
   <?php
   class Signup extends CI_Controller{

   function index(){
   $this->load->view('signup_form');
   }

   function insert_member(){

   //load model 
   $this->load->model('insert_member_model');


   if($q = $this->insert_member_model->new_member()){
       $data['content'] = 'success';
       $this->load->view('trial', $data);
   }
   ```

   }
    }
2. insert_member_model.php - This is the model

   ```
   class Insert_member_model extends CI_Model{
       function new_member(){

       $new_member_data = array(
       'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
       'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
       'username' => 'NULL',
       'password' =>$this->input->post('password'),
       'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address')
   );
   $insert = $this->db->where('membership', $new_member_data);
   return $insert;
    }
   }
   ```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In insert_member_model.php Replace:

```
$this->db->where('membership', $new_member_data);
```

with:

```
$this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_data);
```

To insert the data into the database.